# Username/Directory conflicts with Public Function in Excel Addins

Tags: vba, excel

Windows 7, Excel 2013, Visual Basic for Applications 7.1

I distribute and add-in at work for multiple team members. To get around company IT admin policies, this is stored in the My Documents folder as other C: drive areas present read/write access complications.

The problem with this is that when one user applies one of the public functions to an excel workbook, it doesn't work when another user opens the excel file, since the path the add-in and function are stored in, C:\Users\"username"\Documents\addin\, the "username" has now changed.

Is there anyway to ensure when another user opens a workbook it correctly finds the add-in and public function?

For calling subroutines =Environ("username") works fine to build a path of course, but I'm not sure if this can even be done for a public function being referenced in an excel book?

Comment: can you store the add-in on common shared drive? that is what I did at one point. I kept a local dev version and then stored the prod version on a common shared drive for all others to access

Comment: How are you referencing the add-in? I'd not expect it to use the full file path.

Comment: There's no reference being used. The public function works fine for difference users in their own workbooks, but if user B opens a workbook user A created, the public functions A has entered in the workbooks produce an error for user B. Is there away around this? To Scott's point I want the addin stored locally so it can function without network access.

Comment: If all else fails, most people usually have access to `C:\temp\` :)